# Highcharts version 3 type definitions for typescript

Tags: highcharts, typescript, definitelytyped

Is there a type definition file for Highcharts version 3?

At the moment I can only find this definition:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/highcharts

which is for version 2.3.3.

Or if someone has a list of differences maybe I could help make one :)

Comment: you might want to create one of these : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/labels/Definition:Request Create a new issue and an admin will assign the correct label

Comment: That's what I want to do basarat, but I don't want to have to reverse engineer the highcharts source code to figure out what should go in it.

Answer (score 0):

> Or if someone has a list of differences maybe I could help make one

Your best bet would be the changelog : http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog but it *massive*. You might want to just stick with the current version and update it as you find differences